# Tengo problemas visualizando la página que estoy desarrollando

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Cuando visualizo en mi laptop lo que estoy haciendo, en Chorome o Mozilla, veo algo diferente que si lo veo en otra laptop. En la mía se ven reglas de estilo que ya he borrado y para cuando quiero cambiar algo en el estilo, tengo que colocarle !important porque de lo contrario no se refleja el cambio. 
Por esta razón yo creía que se trataba de un problema de memoria caché, pero aún borrando la caché sigo con el problema. Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/full-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sarala" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=OpenSans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mediaquery23.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo23.css">

      <title>ProblemaMediaQueries</title>

    <style>
     #contenedorCursos{
      position:absolute;
      top: 0rem;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 6rem;
      z-index: 5;
    }
    #paralelogramo2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 1em;
      left: 0;
      float: left;
      width: 100%; 
      height: 63rem; 
      background:  #015382; 
      -webkit-transform: skewY(-8deg); 
      -moz-transform: skewY(-8deg); 
      -o-transform: skewY(-8deg); 
    } 
    .p5{
      position: relative;
      top: -4rem !important; 
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: white;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #texto-p6{
      position: relative;
      top: -4rem !important;
      width: 40%;
      margin: 0 30%;
      text-align: center;
      z-index:25;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 100;
      z-index:1;
    }
    #tituloCurso{
      position: relative;
      top: 10rem;
      width: 100%;
      height: 15rem;
    z-index: 5
    }
    .recto{
      position: relative;
      height: 12em;
      width: 80%;
      margin-left: 20%;
    }
    .menuCursos {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      z-index: 5;
    }
    #menuCursos{
      font-family: 'OpenSans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: white;
      line-height: 1;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .tab1 div {
        display: none;
    }
    .tab1 div:target {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .recuadroDescripcionCursos{
      position: absolute;
      top: 30rem !important;
      left: 50% !important;
      width: 50%;
      height: 20rem;
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      overflow: auto;
      z-index: 5;
     border: 5px dotted blue; 
    }
    li {
        float: left;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: #dcdcdc;
      font-weight: 100;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    li a:hover {
      font-weight: bolder;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style-type: none;
    }

      /* --------------- media queries  ----------------------- */

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #paralelogramo2 {
      position: relative;
      top: 0rem !important;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%; 
      height: 92rem !important; 
      background:  #015382; 
      -webkit-transform: skewY(-8deg); 
      -moz-transform: skewY(-8deg); 
      -o-transform: skewY(-8deg); 
    }}
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
    #contenedorCursos{
      position: absolute ;
      top: 120rem;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 9rem;
      z-index: 5; 
      }}
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
    #caja-contenedor3 {
      position: relative;
      top: 55rem;
      width: 100%;
      height: 95rem;
      z-index: 10;
    }}
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .p5{/* Cursos */
      position: relative;
      top: -120rem !important; 
      font-size: 36px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: white;
      z-index: 10;
    }}
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
    #texto-p6{/* Cursos */
      position: relative;
      top:123rem !important;
      left: -20%;
      width: 80%;
      font-size: 18px;/
    }}
     @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .recuadroDescripcionCursos{
        display: none;
    }}
      @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .tab1 div {
      display: none;
    }}
      @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .tab1 div:target {
        display: inline block !important;
    }}
     @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .recuadroDescripcionCursos{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0rem;
      left: 0!important;
      width: 60%;
      display: block; 
      height: 12.5rem;
      font-size: 16px;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 5;
    }}

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #menuCursoVertical li {
      float: none;
      }}
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      #menuCursoVertical{
        position: relative !important;
        top: -15rem  !important;
        left: -4rem !important;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 25rem;
        height: 13rem;
            }}
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .recto{
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      top: 3em;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      border: none!important;
    }}
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      #cursoG{
        display: none !important;
      }}
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      #cursoP{
        display: block!important;
      }}  
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     #texto{
      font-family: 'OpenSans', sans-serif ;
      font-size: 16px!important;
      color: black!important;
    }}
    </style>
    <body>

    <div id="paralelogramo2"></div> 
    <div id="contenedorCursos">
          <div id="tituloCurso">
            <div id="titulo" class="p5">
                <p>CURSOS</p>
                <div style="margin-left: 46%; margin-right: 46%;border-top: 2px solid #a7f1fc;"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="texto-p6" class="w3-container w3-center">
                <br>
                <p style="color: white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
            </div>
          </div>  
            <br><br>
            <div class="recto">        
                <div class="menuCursos">
                  <ul  id="menuCursoVertical">
                    <li style="list-style:none;" id="cursos"><a href="#programas"><span id="menuCursos">PROGRAMAS</span></a></li>  
                    <li style="list-style:none;" id="cursos"><a href="#primerNivel"><span id="menuCursos">PRIMER NIVEL</span></a></li>
                    <li style="list-style:none;" id="cursos"><a href="#segundoNivel"><span id="menuCursos">SEGUNDO NIVEL</span></a></li>
                    <li style="list-style:none;" id="cursos"><a href="#cursosDeEspecializacion"><span id="menuCursos">CURSOS DE ESPECIALIZACIÓN</span></a></li>
                    <li style="list-style:none;" id="cursos"><a href="#nivelTecnico"><span id="menuCursos">NIVEL TÉCNICO</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div><!-- Fin Menú de Cursos -->   
            </div><!-- Fin Recto -->
          <div  class="tab1" > 
            <div  id="programas" class="recuadroDescripcionCursos">
              <ul>
                <p style="font-size: 26px;font-weight: bold;color:white;">PROGRAMAS</p>         
                <br>
                <li><span class="texto" style="color:#a7f1fc;">DISCOVERY SCUBA DIVING</span>
                    <p class="texto" style="color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. </p>
                </li>
                <li><span class="texto"  style="color:#a7f1fc;">PADI SEAL TEAM</span>
                    <p class="texto"  style="color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
                </li>         
              </ul>
            </div> <!-- Fin de div recuadroDescripcionCursos -->
            <div id="primerNivel" class="recuadroDescripcionCursos">        
              <ul>
                <p style="font-size: 26px;font-weight: bold;color:white;">PRIMER NIVEL</p>         
                <br><br>
                <li><span class="texto"  style="color:#a7f1fc;">AAAAAA</span>
                    <p style="font-size: 1.125em;color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
                    <br>
                </li>            
                <li><span class="texto"  style="color:#a7f1fc;">BBBBBBBBBBB</span>
                    <p style="font-size: 1.125em;color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
                    <br>
                </li>
                <li><span class="texto"  style="color:#a7f1fc;">CCCCCCCCCC</span>
                    <p class="texto" style="font-size: 1.125em;color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
                    <br>
                 </li>    
              </ul>
            </div><!-- Fin de div PrimerNivel -->
            <div id="segundoNivel" class="recuadroDescripcionCursos">        
              <ul>
                <p style="font-size: 26px;font-weight: bold;color:white;">SEGUNDO NIVEL</p>         
                <br><br>
                <li><span class="texto"  style="color:#a7f1fc;">XXXXXXXXXXXXX</span>
                    <p class="texto"  style="color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
                    <br>
                </li>            
                <li><span class="texto" style="color:#a7f1fc;">BBBBBBBBBBB</span>
                    <p class="texto" style="color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
                    <br>
                </li>
                <li><span class="texto"  style="color:#a7f1fc;">CCCCCCCCCC</span>
                    <p style="font-size: 1.125em;color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
                    <br>
                 </li>    
              </ul>
            </div><!-- Fin de div segundoNivel -->
            <div id="cursosDeEspecializacion" class="recuadroDescripcionCursos">        
              <ul>
                <p style="font-size: 26px;font-weight: bold;color:white;">CURSO DE ESPECIALIZACIÓN</p>         
                <br><br>
                <li><span class="texto" style="color:#a7f1fc;">XXXXXXXXXXXXX</span>
                    <p class="texto" style="color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
                    <br>
                </li>            
                <li><span class="texto" style="color:#a7f1fc;">YYYYYYYYYYYYYY</span>
                    <p class="texto" style="color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
                    <br>
                </li>
                <li><span class="texto" style="color:#a7f1fc;">ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</span>
                    <p class="texto" style="color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
                    <br>
                 </li>    
              </ul>
            </div><!-- Fin de div cursoDeEspecializacion -->
            <div id="nivelTecnico" class="recuadroDescripcionCursos">        
              <ul>
                <p style="font-size: 26px;font-weight: bold;color:white;">NIVEL TÉCNICO</p>         
                <br><br>
                <li><span class="texto" style="color:#a7f1fc;">111111111111</span>
                    <p class="texto" style="color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
                     <br>
                </li>           
                <li><span class="texto" style="color:#a7f1fc;">2222111111111111111</span>
                    <p class="texto" style="font-size: 1.125em;color:white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
                     <br>
                </li>       
              </ul>
            </div><!-- Fin de div nivelTecnico -->
          </div><!-- Fin de div tab1 -->              
      </div> <!--   Fin cursos-carousel   -->   
     </div> <!-- Fin contenedorCursos  -->

    </body>
    </html
```

Comment: Puedes poner tu código? Creo que estás llamando dos veces las librerías CSS y por eso se reemplazan.

Comment: Parece ser un problema de media querys. Pero para poder darte una solución necesitamos ver lo que hiciste.

Comment: Podrás incluir estos `mediaquery23.css` y `estilo23.css` archivos? Creo que el problema está en ellos.

Comment: Prueba abriendo la página en distintos navegadores, utiliza el modo incógnito para estar segura que de no es la caché. Luego de eso si los cambios no te los toma sin el !important lo más seguro es que uno de los otros css esté solapando la instrucción de los tuyos, en las herramientas de desarrollador puedes ver ésto último: primero abres con f12 en chrome, luego pulsa ctrl+shift+c y selecciona el componente, te aparece la pestaña "styles/estilos" allí ves las propiedades de css del componente, si ves que la tuya tiene una linea en medio (tachada) es porque está siendo solapada.

Comment: @Kleith no voy a colocar los  archivos  mediaquery23.css y estilo23.css porque son muy largos. Pero los quité y se solucionó el problema en el código de prueba que subí antes. Sin embargo, en el archivo completo, no se ha solucionado. Ahora entiendo que se debe tratar de un problema de solapamiento de estilos css. Voy a revisar con mucho cuidado. Gracias a todos

Comment: control + h borrar datos de navegacion y recargar

Comment: Cuidado! porque en un navegador abres un fichero problemaMediaQueries.html y en otro problemaMediaQueries (2).html y están en otra ruta.

Answer (score 0):

Eso sucede por la caché del navegador, en lo personal yo utilizo [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn) que es una extensión para borrarla.
Con eso tus cambios aparecerán.